# Python tkinter : Input text box displaying as a number

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

This is a part of my ordering program school project. Every time I input something into the entry widget, a random number is dispalyed

```
import tkinter
def doneEditing(e1):
    print(e1)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(width=800, height=428)
root.maxsize(width=800, height=428)


itemAdded = tkinter.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
itemAdded.pack()


e1 = tkinter.Entry(root)

itemAdded.create_window(200, 140, window=e1)

done = tkinter.Button(root, text = 'ENTER', command=lambda: doneEditing(e1))
done.place(x=80, y=90 ,width=120 ,height=26, anchor = 's')


root.mainloop()
```

output = .60223280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change doneEditing into :

```
def doneEditing(e1):
    print(e1.get())
```

In order to get value inside entry box, you need to use get() method.

Further read : https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: a small explanation would go miles into helping the OP avoid further such errors

Comment: you are the goat